# SSRS - Report Manager custom url

Tags: reporting-services

I've configured SSRS report server. Default URL of Report Manager is `http://srv01/Reports`. 

I would like to change it to `http://reporting/Reports`. Can you suggest me how to achieve this?
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was to ask the server administrator to create DNS record for the said address. The issue is not directly related to SSRS.

Comment: To avoid any future problems, you might want to go into the SSRS configuration manager and add a DNS entry containing your new URL.  By default, your instance is *probably* configured to take *all* incoming traffic to the server, which isn't necessarily bad; but reserving the "reporting" DNS entry and binding it to SSRS will better prevent future headaches.